# Error in FreeBSD 8.0 Kernel compilation

Tags: kernel, freebsd, compile, vesa

When trying to compile my own kernel for FreeBSD 8.0, and I'm having some issues. In fact, I can't even re-compile the GENERIC kernel with no changes!

The last few lines before I get errors when running `make depend` are...

```
../../../amd64/amd64/genassym.c:227: error: 'struct pcpu' has no member named 'pc_tss'
../../../amd64/amd64/genassym.c:241: error: 'GUCODE32_SEL' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../amd64/amd64/genassym.c:242: error: 'GUFS32_SEL' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../amd64/amd64/genassym.c:243: error: 'GUGS32_SEL' undeclared here (not in a function)
../../../amd64/amd64/genassym.c:246: error: 'SEL_RPL_MASK' undeclared here (not in a function)
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/i386/compile/GENERIC.
```

This, again, with *no* changes to the GENERIC kernel. My custom kernel is only adding VESA and SC_PIXEL_MODE, but errors in the same way.

EDIT: Interestingly enough, when running `make cleandepend`, I get the following output, despite compiling on an amd64 machine and install of FreeBSD.

```
rm -f .depend machine amd64 cd ../../../modules; MAKEOBJDIRPREFIX=/usr/src/sys/i386/compile/SANDERS/modules KMODDIR=/boot/kernel DEBUG_FLAGS="-g" MACHINE=i386 KERNBUILDDIR="/usr/src/sys/i386/compile/SANDERS" SYSDIR="/usr/src/sys/i386/compile/SANDERS/../../.." make  cleandepend
===> aac (cleandepend) rm -f @ machine amd64 rm -f .depend GPATH GRTAGS GSYMS GTAGS
===> accf_data (cleandepend) rm -f @ machine amd64 rm -f .depend GPATH GRTAGS GSYMS GTAGS
===> accf_dns (cleandepend) rm -f @ machine amd64 rm -f .depend GPATH GRTAGS GSYMS GTAGS
===> accf_http (cleandepend) rm -f @ machine amd64 rm -f .depend GPATH GRTAGS GSYMS GTAGS
===> acpi (cleandepend)
===> acpi/acpi (cleandepend) "Makefile", line 4: "ACPI can only be compiled into the kernel on the amd64 and ia64 platforms"
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/modules/acpi.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/modules.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/src/sys/i386/compile/SANDERS.
```

Any insight would be much appreciated :)

EDIT:

Output of `uname -a` is

```
FreeBSD jbirch.net 8.0-RELEASE FreeBSD 8.0-RELEASE #0: Sat Nov 21 15:02:08 UTC 2009     root@mason.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

and I'm afraid `/usr/make.conf` and `/usr/src.conf` don't exist. I pulled up the relevant man pages, which told me they usually reside in `/etc/`, but they didn't exist there either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the system is trying to build an i386 kernel on your amd64 system.
Can you post the output of "uname -a", the contents of /usr/make.conf and /usr/src.conf please?

**Update**:

Having re-read the original question it appears you're not following the standard build process as outlined in the [Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kernelconfig-building.html), which is probably why things are going wrong. You should be running `make buildkernel` to build a new kernel, and `make installkernel` to install it; `make depend` etc. are run as part of the build internally, but haven't been required to be run manually since the 4.x days.

Comment: That's something I considered, but I'd have thought that you'd be able to build a 32 bit kernel on a 64 bit system. Oh well, I'll edit my original post with the output and contents above.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on re-reading the question: you shouldn't be running "make depend" - all you need is "make buildkernel".

Comment: That seems to be compiling the kernel fine! Thank you for the clarification.